# Positive definite functions on G from Hilbert space vectors?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations, positivity, complete-positivity, reference-request

Let $G$ be a countable discrete group. Given a vector $\xi \in l^{2}(G)$, is there any way to naturally construct a [positive definite function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group) on $G$ using $\xi$?

This question is rather vague and open-ended so I've made this CW, but I'd be *very* appreciative of any references that try to do this.

Comment: Can one define heat kernels here, as in solutions to Laplace-Baltrami diff. equations? if so, that would be the "most natural" way to define at least one posdef function.....

Comment: $\xi \overline{\xi}$?

Or do you want a function $f: G\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(g)>0$ for all $g\in G$?

What about constant function $g \mapsto \\|\xi\\|$?

Comment: @robot: I've edited the question to include a link to what I mean by positive definite function. 

Comment: Thanks. Now where do I report that bug with math display? (Or is it just me who sees \xi directly below g in my previous comment?)

Comment: @robot: you seem to have typed a few double backslashes because of which this have gotten the undesired linebreaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean positive definite in the sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group.  Well, consider the representation of $G$ on $\ell^2(G)$ by $\left(U_g v\right)_h  = v_{g^{-1} h}$.  Then you might take the positive definite $L(\ell^2(G))$-valued function $F$ on $G$ defined by $F(s) = P \circ U_g$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection on $\xi$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Indeed this example is intrinsic to the vector as I asked. Perhaps composition of this with any state would give me scalar-valued positive definite functions, as well...

Comment: Actually, Robert, this sort of p.d. function seemst to give me exactly what I need. I'll accept this answer in a few days if no other contributions appear. Thanks again!